# Is there an opposite concept to trilemma?

Tags: terminology

In economics or other fields, there's a concept [trilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilemma). It means

> A trilemma is a difficult choice from three options, each of which is
> (or appears) unacceptable or unfavourable. There are two logically
> equivalent ways in which to express a trilemma: it can be expressed as
> a choice among three unfavourable options, one of which must be
> chosen, or as a choice among three favourable options, only two of
> which are possible at the same time.

However, I have a new idea relevant to **trilemma**. Say there are three things A, B, C. If any two of them occur, the third must occur as well. That is to say:

```
A, B --> C
C, B --> A
A, C --> B
```

What I am going to ask is is there a concept in philosophy or logic to describe the relationship between A, B, and C I mentioned above?

Comment: Interesting proposal. Give the woman the attention she deserves ... so to speak, mate!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems that it is a chain of interconnected events.

Comment: Seems like ∧, the AND gate logical operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler way to write that in a single sentence is

(A ∨ B ∨ C)  →  (A ⊕ B ⊕ C)

where ∨ is inclusive OR, ⊕ is exclusive OR and → is the material conditional.

Whether this has any useful applications is another matter. One possibility might be a situation in which two people cannot be left together without a chaperone. So, for a given group of three people, any one person may be alone, or all three may be together, but two is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## Dilemma

This is just another type of dilemma. You have to choose one or choose all three. There are no other options.

Answer (score 0):

Such a relationship is a 3-input logic gate that outputs 1 on (001, 010, 100, and 111) and 0 on (000, 011, 101, and 110), where 1 represents truth (or *signal*) and 0 represents falsehood (or *lack of signal*). I don't think it needs any more philosophizing than that.